# fwupd does not detect my hardware

Tags: updates, fwupd

Dear helpful community

I have a StarLabTop that used to update from fwupdmgr GUI but since last update
fwupdmgr does not detect my hardware.

fwupdmgr get-devices returns:
"No hardware detected with firmware update capability"

fwupdmgr get-devices --show-all-devices returns only my processor

I tried purging fwupd and reinstalling but get the same situation.
However when I install fwupd from snap it shows all devices and options except
bios updates which were present before.

I am running 20.04
Can you help me diagnose this?

Thanks